# Function needs to change each word but changes each character

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding

I've got this piece of code

```
dict1={'h':['H'], 'e':['E'], 'l':['LL'], 'o':['O'], 'hello':['HELLO']}

def replfunc(match):     
    return dict1[match.group(0)] 
regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in dict1)) 
with open('/old.txt') as fin, open('/new.txt','w', encoding='UTF-8') as fout:     
   for line in fin:         
    fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))
```

This piece of code currently reads in the old text file and matches characters in this file with dict1 and outputs the new value in the new text file. I would like the above function to match words instead of characters how would i go about altering this? For example if my old text file had the word 'hello' in it the output currently is 'HELLLLO' as it reads in characters but i would like the function to read that the word 'hello' is a key in the dictionary and print out 'HELLO'

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre], especially factoring out the external files. You can replace `fout.write` with `print`, and I think you could replace `fin` with a list of lines, like `['hello']`.

Comment: Another thing - I was getting `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found` but fixed it by switching `dict1`'s values from lists to strings: `dict1 = {'h': 'H', 'e': 'E', 'l': 'LL', 'o': 'O', 'hello': 'HELLO'}`

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, I ran into that too, I also figured it was intended to be what you wrote, and I've updated the answer to reflect that now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that when using an alternation in a regex, the regex engine will always choose the first match in the alternation. Your alternation looks like:

```
(h|e|l|o|hello)
```

so when you process the word `hello`, it will match `h`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o` in turn instead of `hello`. You can work around this by sorting the values in the alternation by length descending so that the longest values are first; this ensures they will be matched if possible:

```py
regex = re.compile('|'.join(sorted((re.escape(x) for x in dict1), key=len, reverse=True)))
```

Now, your alternation looks like

```
(hello|h|e|l|o)
```

and when you call it with `hello` as an input, you get the expected result:

```py
print(regex.sub(replfunc, 'hello'))
print(regex.sub(replfunc, 'helo'))
```

Output

```
HELLO
HELLO
```

Note that with the definition of `dict1` in your question, this code will not run at all (you will get a `TypeError`); the values in `dict1` need to be strings, not lists. I changed it to:

```py
dict1 = {'h': 'H', 'e': 'E', 'l': 'LL', 'o': 'O', 'hello': 'HELLO'}
```

to make the code work.